# how to direct tenant subdomain to correct azure website for a multi tenant website

Tags: azure, dns, multi-tenant

We are building a multi tenant web application that will be hosted on azure as an azure website. When a new tenant registers we want to let this tenant choose in what region he wants the app to be hosted. For example US or EU.

Each new tenant gets a subdomain: tenant1.ourdomain.com, tenant2.ourdomain.com.

If tenant1 chooses EU as his region then tenant1.ourdomain.com should take him to the website hosted in the EU region. If tenant2 chooses the US region then tenant2.ourdomain.com should take him to the website hosted in the US region.

I think that we couldadd a new cname record in our zone file for each new registration that points tenant1.ourdomain.com to the correct server. And I have seen that certain dns providers even provide an api that we could use so we wouldn't have to this manually.

> tenant1.ourdomain.com > eu-site.azurewebsites.net
>
> tenant2.ourdomain.com > us-site.azurewebsites.net

But for this to work we would also need to add the custom domain to the azure website and have an awverify record.

So is this the direction we should look into or is there a better solution?

Comment: Have you ever solved this? I'm looking into a similar set up and am not sure yet how to solve it.